# iOS: Click events not being triggered only on iOS 13

Tags: ios, xib, ios13, ibaction

I have an issue with the button click events on an old app. Everything works OK for iOS versions < 13, but on iOS 13 the button clicks are not working.

This is the code that generates the buttons:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
     super.layoutSubviews()

     var offsetY = CGFloat(0)

     for view in authenticationViews {
         view.button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: offsetY, width: frame.size.width, height: buttonHeight)
         offsetY += buttonsDistance + buttonHeight
         addSubview(view.button)
    }

    height = offsetY
}
```

I think there might be an issue with the constraints, but I am new to iOS and I don't know what to uderstand from this error and how should be fixed:

> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>    (null) ((null), (null))

Comment: What you can do is use the visual debugger to inspect the generated constraints in runtime. Also, adding subviews in `layoutSubviews` could be avoided since the method can be called multiple times. Finally, you could also put a breakpoint at the action method to ensure that the problem is indeed what you suspect it to be (how do you add the target/action btw?)

Comment: Where is target Action?
Also share screenshot

Comment: You can use the [Snapkit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) or any other way in order to make constraints easily.

I guess you need to make constaratins like this:

`view.button.snp.makeConstraints { make in
make.width.equalTo(frame.size.width)
make.height.equalTo(buttonHeight)
}`

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you provide the full code but based on the code provided here're the suggestions.

Since the `layoutSubviews` function can be called multiple times, you should move them inside `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    for view in authenticationViews {
        addSubview(view.button)
    }
}
```

To update the frames of the views based on the layout change, you have to put them in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    var offsetY = CGFloat(0)

    for view in authenticationViews {
        view.button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: offsetY, width: frame.size.width, height: buttonHeight)
        offsetY += buttonsDistance + buttonHeight
    }

    height = offsetY
}
```